# How to find rotation around axis such that x axis aligns to some vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, physics, 3d

Given at 3D transformation matrix T and a 3D vector V. How can I find a rotation that keeps the Z vector in T the same, but aligns the x vector in T as much as possible with V?

I am working with C++ and Eigen, and code is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Your question seems interesting, but users will be less keen to answer it if you don’t add some further context, as for example why your question is interesting, or the things you’ve tried. You can add this in an edit.

Comment: Well, if you fix the $z$-axis, then you must have a rotation about that axis. So, how might you find the nearest point on the $x$-$y$ plane to your target vector? That will give you the rotated $x$-axis direction, and from there you can construct the rotation in several ways, all of which can be found with a quick search.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I believe the below figure and equations show the general approach.  You can just multiply out the final matrix product to get your transformed coordinates in the T coordinate system.  I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: There’s no need to compute $\theta$ explicitly to build the rotation matrix. The sine and cosine can be computed directly from the coordinates of $V$.

Comment: Good answer, but half of it—the important half, to boot—is embedded in a picture. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, and your answer should be comprehensible with images disabled. Please take the time to enter that part of your answer as text. You can find a quick reference for MathJax, which is used here for formatting mathematical expressions, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).